# Adding elements to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Using NumPy:

```
X= numpy.zeros(shape=[1, 4], dtype=np.int)
```

How can I add a list, such as `[1,2,3,4]`? I tried `numpy.add(X,[1,2,3,4])` and `np.hstack((1,2,3,4))` but none of them work!

I know how to use that in standard Python list using `append` method but I want to use numpy for performance.

Comment: Try `numpy.add.at`.

Comment: Could you include the desired output?

Comment: `numpy.add.at(X, [1,2,3,4])` does not work? Is that correct?

Comment: @MSeifert Just appending 4 integers into X

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what that means. With NumPy adding and appending are very different concepts. So including the desired output (in the question) is probably necessary to find out what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays don't change shape after they are created. So after invoking method `zeros((1,4), ...)`, you already have a 1x4 matrix full of zeroes. To set its elements to values other than zeroes, you need to use the assignment operator:

```
X[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # does what you are trying to achieve in your question
X[0, :] = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # equivalent to the above
X[:] = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # same
X[0, 1] = 2  # set the individual element at [0, 1] to 2
```